# python regex return result without characters used for matching

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i would like to perform regex matching, but exclude from the result the characters used for the matching.
consider this sample code

```
import re
string="15  83(B): D17"
result=re.findall(r'\(.+\)',string)
print(result)
```

here's what i get:
['(B)']

here's what i'd like to have:
['B']

i'm after a generic solution to exclude pattern characters used to start/end a match from the result, not just a solution for this precise case. 
for example instead of just ( and ) i could have used more complex patterns to start/end matching, and i still would not want to see them as part of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group for the text you need in output like this:

```
>>> string="15  83(B): D17"
>>> print re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', string)
['B']
```

`(.*?)` is capturing group to match and capture 0 or more characters, non-greedy

In general you can replace starting `(` and ending `)` with anything you have as before and after your match.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it works for this example, but if i wanted to replace '(' with '8' and ')' with '1' to get anything between so: '3(B): D', then it doesn't work? i'm not much skilled with regex as you can see. i would like a start pattern and ending pattern and get everything between, excluding both start /end delimiters. is that not appropriate for regex ?

Comment: Use `print re.findall(r'8(.*?)1', string)` and you will get `['3(B): D']`

Answer (score 0):

**The correct regex is it**

```
r"(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))"
```

*U can change **(** and **)** for anything*

Answer (score 0):

*Lookaheads* and *lookbehinds* can be used to assert that characters are present before and after a certain position without including them in a match.

```
>>> string = "15  83(B): D17"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\().+(?=\))', string)
['B']
```

Here, `(?<=\()` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts that an open parenthesis character comes immediately before this position. `(?=\))` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that a close parenthesis character comes immediately after.

Search the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) for the terms "lookahead" and "lookbehind" for more information.